# Possible to add some static data to TreeView within Glade?

Tags: gtk, glade

I have seen [the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307786/glade-treeview-liststore-data-not-visible-cant-imagine-why) but I am not sure if adding actual data in Glade is possible or not.

I have created a TreeView and added two columns. I created a TreeStore and set it to the TreeView. And how can I add some static data like the following within Glade?

```
Jane 10
Tom  20
Mike 30
Mary 40
```

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.18"/>
  <object class="GtkTreeStore" id="treestore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name name -->
      <column type="string"/>
      <!-- column-name age -->
      <column type="int"/>
    </columns>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Example Window</property>
    <property name="default-width">480</property>
    <property name="default-height">240</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">True</property>
        <property name="model">treestore1</property>
        <property name="enable-grid-lines">both</property>
        <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection"/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="1">
            <property name="resizable">True</property>
            <property name="sizing">autosize</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">Name</property>
            <property name="clickable">True</property>
            <property name="reorderable">True</property>
            <property name="sort-indicator">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText">
                <property name="text">Doge</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="2">
            <property name="resizable">True</property>
            <property name="sizing">autosize</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">Age</property>
            <property name="clickable">True</property>
            <property name="reorderable">True</property>
            <property name="sort-indicator">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText">
                <property name="text">10</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data are stored in a store, such as `GtkListStore`, not in the view. To add them, click the store the widget on the glade.

At the bottom right corner of the image below, there are options to **Add and remove rows**.

[image]

Moreover, to associate the view with the store, the **Text** option in the cell renderer must be set to the corresponding store column.

[image]

Comment: I think I have got the gist, but there still are some weird things. (1)the row editor shows up for GtkListStore, but not GtkTreeStore, which I was using. (2)the name column (gchararray) does not show up in the designer but shows up in the preview. (3)the "column type" text is black under a dark theme, which makes the text difficult to read. (I have appended the screenshot to my OP) Are these bugs? Glade version 3.40.